# How we upload video file in google app engine with ZF2

Tags: php, google-app-engine, zend-framework2

I have uploaded video file in Google App Engine with ZF2. But when we fetch it generate the error:

> "No video with supported format and MIME type found".

Here is the code we are using to upload:

```
$File = $this->params()->fromFiles('video');
$gs_name = $File['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($gs_name, 'gs://testing001'.'/test/video/movie.ogg');
```

Here is the code for fetching it.

```
$object_file = 'gs://testing001/test/video/movie.ogg';
$object_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($object_file);
```

Answer (score 2):

As the name implies, CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl only creates URL for images. You can use CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl instead to serve files directly from GCS: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/public_access

Comment: At the time of uploading i have added proper 'Content-Type' and then  using **CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl()**.Its working fine.Thanks @Mars

Comment: Please mark reply as answer for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: But it is not working with IE.Video is not playing and its display source error.